# HTML OnMouseOver with list image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm really new to all of this so if anybody can help much appreciated - I have 2 questions.

First I tried:

```
<a href="Streaming.html">
  <li>
    <img Src="Streaming.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='HoverStreaming.jpg'; this.height='90px';"; onmouseout="this.src='Streaming.jpg'; this.height='75px';"; width="140" height="75">
  </li>
</a>
```

This worked for changing the image but doesn't seem to work for the height.

Since it's in a list and div is block level I am not using it however I tried putting an ID on the image and using JQuery connecting my html to my other file using `<script type="text/javascript" src="ArchDragonJQuery.js"></script>` and using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Bigger").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            height: "+=30px"
        });
    });
    $("#Bigger").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            height: "-=30px"
        });
    });
});
```

I have tried a few things instead of ID and I still cannot seem to get it to do anything.

So I am wondering A- how can I make the size increase while hovering over, and B- is my jQuery code simply not being correctly linked to the html? if so how do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want an image to have a height of 75px and, when it is hovered over, you want the image to change and have a height of 90px. You can accomplish the 'growing' effect using only CSS using the hover selector.

```css
.hoverGrow img {height:75px; transition:height .4s ease;}
.hoverGrow img:hover {height:90px;}
```

```html
<a href="Streaming.html">
    <li class="hoverGrow">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" onmouseover="this.src='http://placekitten.com/g/300/200';"; onmouseout="this.src='http://placekitten.com/g/200/300';">
    </li>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks this completely solved my issue. still curious about my JQuery (Litteraly just starting JQuery and its really confusing)

Comment: I saw no real problem with your jQuery code. If I had to guess, the ID you gave the image element in your HTML did not match what you had in your jQuery function's selector (IDs are case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

`this.height` is always the height in pixels.  It's a number without units.  You'd want to do `this.height=75`.  That'll change the height attribute on the element itself.  (I think you could probably do this all without script and use CSS only, you can see an example [here](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/pure-css-image-hover/) and [here](http://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/coding/css-image-rollovers/)).

I'm not sure what's wrong with your jQuery case.  Make sure the ID has the same capitalization - you have an unusual capitalization style going on in your example.  IDs are case sensitive in most browsers.  $("#Bigger") will match `<img id="Bigger">` but not `<img id="bigger">`.  You also can't have multiple elements with the same ID - make sure there is only one `id="Bigger"`.

Answer (score 0):

I redid your code and it all works out.  Hopefully you can learn just by looking at what I did.  Your a tag needs to be inside your li tag.  Your Src needs to be src.  keep the code clean.  I know I am typing like shit but I am lazy now :D  Click the link to the codepen

Hope this helps.

```
$('img.image').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({height: '+=30'});
});

$('img.image').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({height: "-=30"});
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYLezx